# How to change the default "angle-left icon" on the sidebar menu in R Shiny to an "angle-right icon"?

Tags: html, css, r, shiny, shinydashboard

I would like to change the default arrow direction (as in the attached pic), so it will point to the right.

[image]

this is the current code:

```
      sidebarMenu(
        menuItem("Market data", tabName = "market data", icon = icon("users"), startExpanded = TRUE,
                 menuSubItem("Performance", tabName = "history", icon = icon("calendar-day")),
                 menuSubItem("SMP", tabName = "SMP", icon = icon("dollar-sign"))
        ),
        
        menuItem("Consumer 1", tabName = "consumer1", icon = icon("user"), startExpanded = FALSE,
                 menuSubItem("Consumption", tabName = "consumption", icon = icon("history")),
                 menuSubItem("Profile", tabName = "profile", icon = icon("poll-h")),
                 menuSubItem("Forecast engine", tabName = "forecast", icon = icon("brain"))
        )
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: You should put together a small *runnable* example that illustrates the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### General

In general, to change the defaults in `shinydashboard` you need to find the correct CSS tags for these elements and then add your own custom CSS file to overwrite the default.

If you plan on making a lot of these changes, the `shinydashboard` framework might not be right for you.

#### Specific solution to your question

With some poking around in the browser, you'll see that the tag for these arrows are `.fa-angle-left:before`. The symbol showed is defined with the following CSS:

```css
.fa-angle-left:before{content:"\f104"}
```

To change it to a right arrow we need to change `\f104` to `\f105`:

As noted [in the documentation](https://rstudio.github.io/shinydashboard/appearance.html#css), you can add your own CSS-file as such:

- Add the file `www/custom.css` to the same folder as your Shiny dashboard is located.
- Add the following code to it:

```css
.fa-angle-left:before{content:"\f105"}
```

If you want the arrow to still point down after you click it you also need to add

```css
.sidebar-menu li.active>a>.fa-angle-left, .sidebar-menu li.active>a>.pull-right-container>.fa-angle-left {
    transform: rotate(90deg);
}
```

- When this is done, you need to add the following code to your `sidebarMenu`:

```r
tags$head(
          tags$link(rel = "stylesheet", type = "text/css", href = "custom.css")
        )
```

##### Working example

**app.R**

```r
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)

ui <- dashboardPage(
  dashboardHeader(),
  dashboardSidebar(
    dashboardSidebar(
      sidebarMenu(
        tags$head(
          tags$link(rel = "stylesheet", type = "text/css", href = "custom.css")
        ),
        menuItem(
          "Market data",
          tabName = "market data",
          icon = icon("users"),
          menuSubItem("SMP", tabName = "SMP", icon = icon("dollar-sign"))
        )
      )
    )
  ),
  dashboardBody()
)

server <- function(input, output) {}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

**www/custom.css**

```css
.fa-angle-left:before{content:"\f105"}

.sidebar-menu li.active>a>.fa-angle-left, .sidebar-menu li.active>a>.pull-right-container>.fa-angle-left {
    transform: rotate(90deg);
}
```